# Sharpdevelop TFS plugin

Tags: plugins, tfs, client, sharpdevelop

Is there a TFS plugin for use with sharp develop? From what i can see on google, there were a couple of summer of code projects in this general direction but i cant seem to find a definitive answer.

Alternatively if there is no plugin, what are my options for TFS clients?

Comment: In version 5.1.0.5216 of SharpDevelop there is an additional resource manager you can install an addin for this. [SharpDev Tfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dMLg.png)

Answer (score 5):

Without support built-in to the SharpDevelop IDE, the easiest option would be to use the **TFS Windows Shell Extensions** to interact with TFS from Windows Explorer. See [towards the bottom of this post](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) for more information - although it mentions TFS 2008, the feature is much the same in 2010.

[image]

To start using these, you will need to do the following:

1. Install [Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=329) (to get the TFS object
   model on your machine), *(Note, you can also get the object model w/o VS by googling 'TFS Object Model Free', currently at this link: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a37e19fb-3052-4fc9-bef7-4a4682069a75 )*
2. Install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f)
3. Browse to a folder on your machine that is mapped in a a TFS workspace (establish one first if you need to)
4. You should then be able to right-click the files and choose **Team Foundation Server > Check-In** (or similar)

[image]

Comment: SharpDevelop supports Git and SVN. That wish list bullet point in the wiki is for bug tracking system integration with source control. However you are correct that there is no support for TFS and using the separate TFS client is the best approach.